# Is the field $F = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}(-y,x,0)$ conservative outside of the z-axis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

> Is the field $$F = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}(-y,x,0)$$ conservative outside of the z-axis, i.e $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

I've found a potential function $U(x,y,z) = -arctan(\frac{x}{y}) + C$ which satisfies:

$$(\frac{dU}{dx}, \frac{dU}{dy}, \frac{dU}{dz}) = F$$ since 
$$\frac{dU}{dx} = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$\frac{dU}{dy} = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$\frac{dU}{dx} = 0$$

So my answer would be that $F$ is conservative, since I've satisifed the very definition of a conservative field, but the answer is that it is not. Why?

Comment: Is $\arctan$ well-defined everywhere outside $z$-axis?

Comment: If the field were conservative its work along the the unit circle centered at the origin of the $z=0$ plane would be zero. Is that so?

Comment: @edm Yes? except for when $y=0$, which is handled in the initial condition $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ no?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah I realize that, so it's obviously not conservative, but I don't get why my method does not work in determining that.

Comment: The condition $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ does not imply that $y$ can never be zero. The condition means that $x$ and $y$ are not zero at the same time - but $y = 0$ is satisfied at a point like $(x,y) = (1,0)$. As for why your method does not work, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your potential function is not defined on all of $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{z\textrm{-axis}\}$: $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$ does not exist if $y = 0$. So, you've shown that if $D\subseteq\Bbb R^3$ is a domain whose intersection with the plane $y = 0$ is empty, $\left.\mathbf{F}\right|_D$ (the vector field restricted to $D$) is conservative. Similarly, you could construct a potential function away from the $x = 0$ plane.

The vector field above is closed (i.e. $\nabla\times\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$), but a closed vector field is not necessarily conservative. The converse is true in two dimensions if the domain of definition of the vector field is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) and in three dimensions if the domain of definition is [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), but $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{z\textrm{-axis}\}$ (the domain of $\mathbf{F}$) is not simply connected (hence not contractible), so even though the vector field is closed, it need not be conservative. And indeed, it isn't: if you compute the line integral over the unit circle in the $z = C$ plane centered at $(0,0)$, you will obtain a nonzero answer, which shows that $\mathbf{F}$ cannot be conservative on any domain containing $(0,0,C)$ for any $C$.

However, there is good news. If you restrict your vector field to *any* simply connected domain which avoids the $z$-axis, your restricted vector field will be conservative. You can construct a potential function on this domain much like you did with $\tan^{-1}(x/y)$, although you will need to be a little careful in constructing the potential function if the domain intersects both the $x = 0$ plane and the $y = 0$ plane.